# HttpInterceptor is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-http-interceptors

I am using `HttpInterceptor` to add Auth token and the issue is that the interceptor is adding the token for first request and after that it stops working. Here is my Interceptor Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import {CommonService} from "./common.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: CommonService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = this.auth.getAuthToken();
    const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+authToken.access_token} });
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Here is the App Module provider section

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
    multi: true
  }],
```

Let me know what is the wrong with the code.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: You declare it at the providers array and you use "providedIn: 'root'" at the injectable annotation. Did you try to remove the providedIn from @Injectable?

Comment: I am getting following errors 

401 (Unauthorized) 

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: removing "providedIn: 'root'" did not help.

Comment: Seems that you have classic CORS problem. Your interceptor has nothing to do with it.

Comment: To work around CORS, depends what type of backend you use, you may have to set CORS policy in your API. Beside, if you are testing from Chrome, check out this answer which can help bypass Chrome's CORS check: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/5395603